# Secure User Authentication with Java

Tags: java, security, authentication

I am currently trying to have a user authentication system with java but my issue is if a user decompiles my app it will show the database login information is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Credentials should not be stored in plain text, and if it is a Java web application they should not have access to the server application components. The authentication server should not reside with the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, if your client app connects directly to the database. The best defense is to set up a server that does the database interactions and have the client communicate with the server. You have to decide how important your data is and whether its worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Username and Password and hash it somehow.
Store the hash and the username
when a user trys to login, it first makes sure that the username exists, and then attempts to hash the entered password and username.
if the hashes match, thd password was correct
(this might be completely wrong if it is tell me)